# Cannot substitute null values in particular column of DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the code that creates `RDD[LabeledPoint]` named `dfLP`. Each `LabeledPoint` has:

1. the value of a column `target` of DataFrame `df`
2. points that correspond to the indices of columns of `df` specified in `featInd`.

When I execute this code, I get the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Value at index 2 in null

As far as I understand it means that some row of `df` has values `null` that cannot be cast to `Double`.

```
val targetInd = df.columns.indexOf("target")
val ignored = List("target")
val featInd = df.columns.diff(ignored).map(df.columns.indexOf(_))

val dfLP = df.rdd.map(r => LabeledPoint(
    r.getDouble(targetInd),
    Vectors.dense(featInd.map(r.getDouble(_)))
))
```

The error refers to the line `Vectors.dense(featInd.map(r.getDouble(_)))`, where `featInd` is `Array[Int]`. This array contains only indices of existing columns of `df`. For example `[1, 2, 3]` for `df` that has `10` columns.

**UPDATE:**

I detected the column (`col1`) that has some `null` values. However after executing `df = df.na.fill("0",Seq("col1"))` I still have the same error. When I print `df` I still see `null` values. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried `na.fill` function but the following will definitely remove your `nullpointerexception` by using `Option` function

```
val dfLP = df.rdd.map(r => {
  LabeledPoint(Option(r.getDouble(targetInd)) getOrElse 0D, Vectors.dense(featInd.map(ind => Option(r.getDouble(ind)) getOrElse 0D)))
})
```

This will hide the fact that your data has null values though. 
Hope the answer helps